# Is it possible to use firebase query with Redux-toolkit or RTK Query in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-toolkit

I am wonderning like can we use firebase query with Redux-toolkit createAsyncThunk or RTK Query in React ?

Comment: https://morioh.com/p/d1995e04dd56 you might find this useful, it's a tutorial on using firestore database with RTK Query

Answer (score 24):

Yes, instead of writing RTK Query endpoints with a `query` property, you would write them with a [`queryFn`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-queryfn) instead and use [`fakeBaseQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-a-queryfn) instead of `fetchBaseQuery`.

```js
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getSomeDataFromFirebase: build.query({
      queryFn(arg) {
        try {
          const result = ... // call firebase here
          return { data: result.something }
        } catch (e) {
          return { error: e }
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this information.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same thing, but for consistency reasons mostly. What are the main benefits of having rtk query manage your firestore data fetching? @phry

Comment: @djangodev it depends: there are some specialized libraries like redux-query out there - those might be even better suited, depending on how exactly you want to use them. If you were using plain Redux for this before, using RTK Query will save you tons of code - but it is a "generic" solution not tailored to firestore.

Comment: @phry how is RTK Query compared to [React Query Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-query-firebase)? 
You would probably use either RTK or a React Query based solution right?

Answer (score 10):

normally in redux query we use `fetchBaseQuery` but since we are just querying the database and firebase does not have any put,delete,update api, we use `fakeBaseQuery()`

```
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import {collection,doc,getDoc,getDocs} from "firebase/firestore";
//export const db = getFirestore(app) inside firebase setting
import {db} from "../firebaseConfig"


export const postsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "posts",
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  tagTypes: ["Post"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchPosts: builder.query({
      // since we are using fakeBaseQuery we use queryFn
      async queryFn() {
        try {
          // posts is the collection name
          const blogRef = collection(db, "posts");
          const querySnaphot = await getDocs(blogRef);
          let posts = [];
          querySnaphot?.forEach((doc) => {
            posts.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
          });
          return { data: posts };
        } catch (error) {
          return { error };
        }
      },
      providesTags: ["Post"],
    }),
    //***************SINGLE ITEM FETCHING*************** */
    fetchSinglePost: builder.query({
      async queryFn(id) {
        try {
          const docRef = doc(db, "posts", id);
          const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
          return { data: snapshot.data() };
        } catch (error) {
          return { error };
        }
      },
      providesTags: ["Post"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useFetchPostsQuery, useFetchSinglePostQuery } = postsApi;
```