# Whenever filtering my queries to Firebase I get nothing, but an empty array. Not even an error message to work with. Can someone spot what's wrong?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, rtk-query, next.js13

I can get no result from my query to firebase collections when the 'Where' function is called. I can get the whole collection, tho.

```
fetchComments: builder.query({  
        queryFn: async(post) => {
            // func should take postId, and query(collection(firestore, 'comments'), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')) should
            try {
                const commentsQuery = query(collection(firestore, 'comments'), where('postId', '==', post?.id), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
                const querySnapShot = await getDocs(commentsQuery);

                return { data: querySnapShot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data() }))};
            } catch (error) {
                return { data: null };
            }
        },
        providesTags: ['Comment']
    }),
```

Please also see types def.

```
export interface Comment {
id?: string;
postTitle: string;
createdBy: string;
creatorDisplayName: string;
communityName: string;
numberOfUpvotes?: number;
content: string;
postId: string;
createdAt: Timestamp;
```

}

```
export interface Post {
id?: string;
authorId: string;
authorUsername: string | null;
communityName: string | undefined;
communityImageUrl?: string;
title: string;
text: string;
numberOfComments: number;
numberOfUpvotes: number;
imageUrl?: string;
createdAt: Timestamp | FieldValue;
```

};

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587312/is-it-possible-to-use-firebase-query-with-redux-toolkit-or-rtk-query-in-react/73980660#73980660

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out... I have used this very same reference to built my endpoints, which mostly work just fine till the try filtering the results with the where function. I am still stuck trying the get specific entries.